# Spring AntMatcher and Filters in configuration

Tags: javascript

I am trying to have a filter working acording to a specific URI.
basically, I'd like to have

```
/api/ --> activate JwtFilter
/apikey/ --> activate ApiKeyFilter
```

I did this in my spring configuration:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/authenticate").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.antMatcher("/api/**").addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http.antMatcher("/apikey/**").addFilterBefore(apiKeyFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }
```

When I try URI I have:

```
/test/test ---> is activating ApiKeyFilter
/api/test ---> is activating ApiKeyFilter
/apikey/test --> is activating BOTH
```

I think I am missing something...
Thanks!